# Rename filename on S3 using S3Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to rename filename on AWS drive. My connection with AWS is configured. I prepared a piece of code that should copy new file with changed filename, but it copies file with unchanged filename.

```
void updateFileName(String key, String newKey, String newName) {
    CopyObjectRequest copyReq = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
            .copySource(bucket + "/" + key)
            .destinationBucket(bucket)
            .destinationKey(newKey)
            .contentDisposition("attachment; filename=" + newName)
            .build();

    s3Client.copyObject(copyReq);
}
```

Comment: There is no **delete** command in Amazon S3. You will need to **copy** the object, then **delete** the original object.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. In the builder of `CopyObjectRequest` I added `.metadataDirective(MetadataDirective.REPLACE)`. The code should look like:

```
void updateFileName(String key, String newKey, String newName) {
CopyObjectRequest copyReq = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
        .copySource(bucket + "/" + key)
        .destinationBucket(bucket)
        .destinationKey(newKey)
        .contentDisposition("attachment; filename=" + newName)
        .metadataDirective(MetadataDirective.REPLACE)
        .build();

s3Client.copyObject(copyReq);}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official AWS Docs have a section called "Copy, Move, or Rename Objects" that you can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#copy-object).

It states:

> You can copy an object from one bucket to another by using the AmazonS3 client’s `copyObject` method. It takes the name of the bucket to copy from, the object to copy, and the destination bucket name.

The relevant piece of code for you is this:

```java
s3.copyObject(from_bucket, object_key, to_bucket, object_key);
```

You can also find a full example on GitHub [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/java/example_code/s3/src/main/java/aws/example/s3/CopyObject.java).

Something to note, on AWS S3 the concepts of update/rename/move an object don't really apply. SDKs and other higher level libraries might expose APIs that allow to perform such operations but at the end of the day you're either rewriting the same object in case of an update or writing a new one and deleting the old one in case of rename/move.

This is also explained in a note in the same page I linked above:

> You can use `copyObject` with `deleteObject` to move or rename an object, by first copying the object to a new name (you can use the same bucket as both the source and destination) and then deleting the object from its old location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In project is used newer version of SDK. Your example is based on SDK 1.

Comment: I've been looking at the SDK v2 [docs](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/CopyObjectRequest.html) and your code looks okay, the only command I am not sure it's necessary is the `contentDisposition` one but I am not an expert of the Java SDK so I am not sure it's the issue here. Regardless of the SDK version you're using, the comment about how S3 works still applies.